# Revolving animation, that follows finger, of uibuttons that follows outer path of circle

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton, core-animation

I am looking for a little guidance to start figuring out an animation that tracks finger movement and moves a collection of UIButtons along the outer path of a circle

[image]

I am picturing it will kind of have a revolver feel to it. Like each one locks into place at the bottom

or like the swiping through one of the slide inserts of these

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm upvoting your question, now you are able to post an image

Answer (score 6):

(Sample code on [GitHub](https://github.com/CanTheAlmighty/RadialGesture))

It's not really that difficult, there's just a lot of trigonometry involved.

Now, what I'm going to describe now, **is not an animation**, since you requested for it to track the position of your finger in the title. An animation would involve its own timing function, but since you're using the touch gesture, we can use the inherent timing that this event has and just rotate the view accordingly. (TL;DR: The user keeps the time of the movement, not an implicit timer).

### Keeping track of the finger

First of all, let's define a convenient class that keeps track of the angle, I'm gonna call it  `DialView`. It's really just a subclass of UIView, that has the following property:

#### DialView.h

```
@interface DialView : UIView

@property (nonatomic,assign) CGFloat angle;

@end
```

#### DialView.m

```
- (void)setAngle:(CGFloat)angle
{
    _angle = angle;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
}
```

The `UIButton`s can be contained within this view (I'm not sure if you want the buttons to be responsible for the rotation? I'm gonna use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, since it's the most convenient way).

Let's build the view controller that will handle a pan gesture inside our `DialView`, let's also keep a reference to DialView.

#### MyViewController.h

```
@class DialView;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

// The previously defined dial view
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet DialView *dial;

// UIPanGesture selector method    
- (IBAction)didReceiveSpinPanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture;

@end
```

It's up to you on how you hook up the pan gesture, personally, I made it on the nib file. Now, the main body of this function:

#### MyViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)didReceiveSpinPanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    // This struct encapsulates the state of the gesture
    struct state
    {
        CGPoint touch;          // Current touch position
        CGFloat angle;          // Angle of the view
        CGFloat touchAngle;     // Angle between the finger and the view
        CGPoint center;         // Center of the view
    };
    
    // Static variable to record the beginning state
    // (alternatively, use a @property or an _ivar)
    static struct state begin;
    
    CGPoint touch = [gesture locationInView:nil];
    
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        begin.touch  = touch;
        begin.angle  = self.dial.angle;
        begin.center = self.dial.center;
        
        begin.touchAngle = CGPointAngle(begin.touch, begin.center);
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        struct state now;
        now.touch   = touch;
        now.center  = begin.center;
        
        // Get the current angle between the finger and the center
        now.touchAngle = CGPointAngle(now.touch, now.center);
        
        // The angle of the view shall be the original angle of the view
        // plus or minus the difference between the two touch angles
        now.angle = begin.angle - (begin.touchAngle - now.touchAngle);
        
        self.dial.angle = now.angle;
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // (To be Continued ...)
    }
}
```

`CGPointAngle` is a method invented by me, it's just a nice wrapper for `atan2` (and I'm throwing `CGPointDistance` in if you call NOW!):

```
CGFloat CGPointAngle(CGPoint a, CGPoint b)
{
    return atan2(a.y - b.y, a.x - b.x);
}

CGFloat CGPointDistance(CGPoint a, CGPoint b)
{
    return sqrt(pow((a.x - b.x), 2) + pow((a.y - b.y), 2));
}
```

The key here, is that there's two angles to keep track:

1. The angle of the view itself
2. The angle formed between your finger and the center of the view.

In this case, we want to have the view's angle be `originalAngle + deltaFinger`, and that's what the above code does, I just encapsulate all the state in a struct.

### Checking the radius

If that you want to keep track on "the border of the view", you should use the `CGPointDistance` method and check if the distance between the `begin.center` and the `now.finger` is an specific value.

That's homework for ya!

### Snapping back

Ok, now, this part is an actual animation, since the user no longer has control of it.

The snapping can be achieved by having a set defined of angles, and when the finger releases the finger (Gesture ended), snap back to them, like this:

```
else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    // Number of "buttons"
    NSInteger buttons = 8;
    
    // Angle between buttons
    CGFloat angleDistance = M_PI*2 / buttons;
    
    // Get the closest angle
    CGFloat closest = round(self.dial.angle / angleDistance) * angleDistance;
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 animations:^{
        self.dial.angle = closest;
    }];
}
```

The `buttons` variable, is just a stand-in for the number of buttons that are in the view. The equation is super simple actually, it just abuses the rounding function to approximate to the closes angle.

Comment: Hi, thank you again. I am having a little trouble figuring out how to add the button to the rotating view without the actual button rotating. Kind of like a ferris wheel

Comment: (Seems that we live in completely different time zones) Did you try appling an inverse transform to the buttons within?