# Drag uibutton around fixed path of circle. (Kind of like a ferris wheel)

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to figure out how to drag a UIButton around a circle while maintaining its orientation and also pushing the rest of the buttons along the circle. Basically constrain it to the radius of a circle.

[image: Before drag]

If you dragged A around the circle B would stay in front of it and also go around the circle. It is kind of like if you looked at a ferris wheel from the side

[image: after drag]
thanks in advance

Comment: Is there some programming class or job application that is asking this question?  This is the second or third time I have seen this question today.  Edit: found them: [Today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953283/ios-implement-a-rotating-wheel-with-custom-views-being-horizontally-stationary) and [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953283/ios-implement-a-rotating-wheel-with-custom-views-being-horizontally-stationary)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revolving animation, that follows finger, of uibuttons that follows outer path of circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936955/revolving-animation-that-follows-finger-of-uibuttons-that-follows-outer-path-o)

Comment: total coincidence, thanks I'll take a look at those